# Where in the OS can a System Management Interrupt originate

Tags: x86, operating-system, interrupt

System Management Mode (SMM) is always entered through a System Management Interrupt (SMI) which is triggered by [a number of events](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/9-series-chipset-pch-datasheet.pdf#page=153) (e.g. power button press, PCIE hot-plug message, write to AMP_STS register, etc.). Many of these appear to originate from hardware - button presses, GPIO, timers, etc..

At least some SMM functionality must be exposed to the OS, though. Clearly, `systemctl poweroff` for example, originates from userspace, not hardware.

When looking into SMM, a decent amount of information is available about the inner workings of such a call - at some point, register `B2h` is written to, the processor enters SMM, invoking an appropriate SMI handler in the firmware, the source code for which can be examined (as in the case of [coreboot](https://github.com/coreboot/coreboot/tree/master/src/cpu/x86/smm) for example).

However, I have been unable to find any info on what exactly happens *before* entering SMM. What exactly writes to `B2h`? Is it the kernel? A driver? Could it be a userspace application? `systemd`? What priviledge level (ring) is required to invoke a SMI? Overall, what are the common "paths" between a user and SMM?

Comment: I believe the answer you are looking for is [ACPI](https://uefi.org/htmlspecs/ACPI_Spec_6_4_html/#). The OS basically executes some code given by the firmware in AML language. This code is chipset specific, so an OS can use it without knowing the specific details of the motherboard and other hardware. (it's a bit more complicated than that, but a look through the spec should shed some light)